# Converting Text to Date Time

Tags: r, datetime

I want to convert the below column to DateTime, I tried using `as.Date`, `anytime` but I get wrong answer. Please see below:

```
time_stamp
20171001010114
20171001015436
20171001092516
20171001093101
20171001093739
20171001095059
20171001100741
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `lubridate`:

```
df$time_stamp <- lubridate::ydm_hms(df$time_stamp)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  time_stamp         
  <dttm>             
1 2017-01-10 01:01:14
2 2017-01-10 01:54:36
3 2017-01-10 09:25:16
4 2017-01-10 09:31:01
5 2017-01-10 09:37:39
6 2017-01-10 09:50:59
7 2017-01-10 10:07:41
```

Using this data:

```
text <- "time_stamp
        20171001010114
        20171001015436
        20171001092516
        20171001093101
        20171001093739
        20171001095059
        20171001100741"

df <- readr::read_table(text)
```

Comment: Yes Almost. I did the same thing but i am getting warings:

Warning message:
 26780 failed to parse.

My code:
data$tstamp <- ydm_hms(data$ts)

Comment: This works:

data$tstamp <- ymd_hms(data$ts)

Thanks @tyluRp

Comment: Happy to help @MirzaHashim

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with `POSIXlt` datetime, then consider using `strptime`:

```
x <- "20171001010114"
ts_posix <- strptime(time_stamp, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
ts_posix

[1] "2017-10-01 01:01:14 CEST"
```